# Generation of apparently inconsistent alloy instances

Tags: java, instances, alloy

I am doing a metamodel in alloy for a subset of Java.

Below we have some signatures:

```
abstract sig Id {}
sig Package{}
sig ClassId, MethodId,FieldId extends Id {}
abstract sig Accessibility {}
one sig public, private_, protected extends Accessibility {}
abstract sig Type {}
abstract sig PrimitiveType extends Type {}
one sig Int_, Long_ extends PrimitiveType {}

sig Class extends Type {
    package: one Package,
    id: one ClassId,
    extend: lone Class,
    methods: set Method,
    fields: set Field
}
sig Field {
    id : one FieldId,
    type: one Type,
    acc : lone Accessibility
}
sig Method {
    id : one MethodId,
    param: lone Type,
    acc: lone Accessibility,
    return: one Type,
    b: one Body
}
abstract sig Body {}
sig LiteralValue extends Body {} // returns a random value
abstract sig Qualifier {}
one sig this_, super_ extends Qualifier {}
sig MethodInvocation extends Body {
    id_methodInvoked : one Method, 
    q: lone Qualifier
}
//        return new A().k();
sig ConstructorMethodInvocation extends Body {
    id_Class : one Class, 
    cmethodInvoked: one Method
}{
    (this.@cmethodInvoked in (this.@id_Class).methods) || (this.@cmethodInvoked in ((this.@id_Class).^extend).methods && (this.@cmethodInvoked).acc != private_)
}
//        return x;
//        return this.x;
//        return super.x;
sig FieldInvocation extends Body {
    id_fieldInvoked : one Field, 
    qField: lone Qualifier
}
//        return new A().x;
sig ConstructorFieldInvocation extends Body {
    id_cf : one Class, 
    cfieldInvoked: one Field
}{
    (this.@cfieldInvoked in (this.@id_cf).fields) || ( this.@cfieldInvoked in ((this.@id_cf).^extend).fields && (this.@cfieldInvoked).acc != private_)
}
```

In Java language, we can only invoke a method inside a class (through the instantiation of this class) if this method is not a private method. I tried to represent this restriction in my alloy model through the following signature:

```
sig ConstructorMethodInvocation extends Body {

    id_Class : one Class, 
    cmethodInvoked: one Method
}{
    (this.@cmethodInvoked in (this.@id_Class).methods || this.@cmethodInvoked in ((this.@id_Class).^extend).methods && (this.@cmethodInvoked).acc != private_)
```

Thus, a ConstructorMethodInvocation signature in alloy tries to represent a construction in java like new A().x(). In addition, method x() can only be invoked if it is not a private method of class A. So, i put the following restriction (inside ConstructorMethodInvocation signature) in order to avoid calling of private methods of class id_Class:

(this.@cmethodInvoked in (this.@id_Class).methods || this.@cmethodInvoked in ((this.@id_Class).^extend).methods && (this.@cmethodInvoked).acc != private_)

However, despite this restriction, the solver insists on generating instances (for ConstructorMethodInvocation) where cmethodInvoked is a private method of id_Class. The same happens likewise with ConstructorFieldInvocation .

Does anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you misplaced parentheses in the appended facts of the `ConstructorMethodInvocation` sig: the way it is now, you have a top-level disjunction which allows instances where either (`cmethodInvoked` is  in `id_Class.methods`) OR (it's in `id_Class.^extend.methods` and not private).  If you change that appended facts block to

```
{
   this.@cmethodInvoked in this.@id_Class.*extend.methods 
   this.@cmethodInvoked.acc != private_
}
```

you'll get the intended behavior (the star operator (`*`) is the reflective transitive closure and it basically means the same as the original disjunction you intended to write; you could still use your old constraint and just fix the parentheses).

To check that there can't exist any `ConstructorMethodInvocation` instances where the method is private, I executed

```
check {
  no c: ConstructorMethodInvocation {
    c.cmethodInvoked.acc = private_
  }
}
```

which found no counterexample.

Comment: Hi, Aleksandar, i understand that the instance generated by your code is correct since you are preventing it to invoke a private method through "c.cmethodInvoked.acc != private_". For this reason, i did not understand your argument. My intention is almost the same but i have also to link this method with the class referenced by id_class. I imagine that i would preventing to invoke a private method from this class by doing: "this.@cmethodInvoked in (this.@id_Class).methods) || (this.@cmethodInvoked in ((this.@id_Class).^extend).methods && (this.@cmethodInvoked).acc != private_"

Comment: continuing: i would prevent to invoke a private method from this class, except in the case that the method is itself in the class, where the invocation is allowed and it is hold by the first part of the fact: this.@cmethodInvoked in (this.@id_Class).methods). In order to better clarify, below is an example of instance generated: [continue in next comment due to characters limitation]

Comment: public class Teste {
  public static void main(  String[] args){
    new ClassId_6().methodid_0();
    System.out.println(new ClassId_6().methodid_0());
  }
} which should not be possible since methodid_0 is a private method and the ConstructorMethodInvocation signature is preventing this generation.

Comment: i made a mistake with the first part "this.@cmethodInvoked in (this.@id_Class).methods)". But even when i put in the signature the restriction: "(this.@cmethodInvoked in (this.@id_Class).methods || this.@cmethodInvoked in ((this.@id_Class).^extend).methods && this.@cmethodInvoked.acc != private_)", the result is the same.

Comment: I guess I did not (and I still don't) understand what your question is.  I thought you were asking why all the generated instances happen to invoke only private methods.  My response to that was that it is not true that all valid instances of your model always invoke a private method.  Can you please edit your question and try to explain better what exactly you find wrong with your model?

Comment: ok Aleksandar, i just edited my question. Please let me know if it is clear now. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: you explicitly wrote parentheses around the AND clause